# How can i monitor syslog messages in c# console app with TCP

Tags: c#, tcp, monitoring, syslog

In my application, i need to monitor all messages sent by syslog.
I've tried with UDP, but after one message, i didn't respond anymore (no error, just no heads up anymore). And setting up a tcp server isn't really the solution either i think.

Can anyone guide me to a solution where i can log messages form syslog with tcp (normally on port 514).

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured this out at last.
It seems that syslog messages use UDP as standard. There's no monitoring with TCP when syslog option is enabled.

Maybe this is still helpfull to others